# дан массив чисел от -20 до + 20 шаг 1 все отрицательно нечётные числа превратить в нули

Tags: python

дан массив чисел от -20 до + 20 шаг 1
все отрицательно нечётные числа превратить в нули, все отрицательно чётные в единицы.
все положительно нечётные в 10 все положительно чётные в 100.
Немного не работает, как починить?

```
a = [-20,-19,-18,-17,-16,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19, 20]
print(a)
i = 0
m = 20
while i < m:
    if a[i] < 0:
        if a[i] % 2 == 0:
            a[i] = 1
            m -= 1
        else:
            a[i] = 0
            m -= 1
    if a[i] > 0:
        if a[i] % 2 == 0:
            a[i] = 100
            m -= 1
        else:
            a[i] = 10
            m -= 1
print(a)
```

Comment: Что значит *Немного не работает*?

Comment: Значит неправильно работает

Comment: при вычислении остатка брать abs(a[i]) % 2 == 0 + число 0 какое? парное или нет?

Comment: Что значит *неправильно работает*? Приведите ожидаемый и реальный результат

Comment: А где добавление итератора? Почему m = 20, а не длине массива? В общем, странный цикл)

Comment: ++нужно брать число m за 41

Comment: Перечитай в учебнике как делать итерации по списку, чтобы не городить такой огород.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [
    -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0,
     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
]

print(a)

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] < 0:
        if a[i] % 2 == 0:
            a[i] = 1
        else:
            a[i] = 0
    elif a[i] > 0:
        if a[i] % 2 == 0:
            a[i] = 100
        else:
            a[i] = 10

print(a)
```